# Accidentally used sausage meat in meatloaf

Tags: meatloaf

I tried a new recipe that called for ground pork and beef. I accidentally used pork sausage. Noticing my mistake, I cooked a sample and don't like it! How can I mask the sausage taste before baking the entire batch?

Comment: As long as I don't "stub my toe" and make it salty, would powdered beef bullion work?

Comment: could you just add some ground beef to it? also what else is in the recipe?

Comment: With my budget, I was hopeful for a alternate solution but...I'm sure that will be the best fix! The recipe has ground beef, pork (now sausage) onions, peppers, onion soup mix, crackers, eggs, Worcestershire, tomato paste, sour cream, salt& pepper. The topping is ketchup, brown sugar, scant amt of jalapeno juice & Worcestershire

Comment: I'm almost ashamed to tell... I've been a cook most all my life and simply wanted to try something new but...I guess after having a stroke and, at my ripe ole age of 56, when it comes to making lg batches...I should stick with what I know! Lol

Comment: the "sausage taste" is presumably the spices in it rather than the pork itself. You can perhaps cover it up by making the meat mix spicier with black pepper, some of that jalapeno juice, some chopped jalapenos, etc. You could also add more plain unspiced meat to make a larger meatloaf closer to the taste you wanted.

Comment: A "perhaps more budget friendly" dilutant than "more meat" would be to take it in a "cottage pie" direction with potato, or a "chili" direction with legumes - perhaps split peas rather than beans for faster cooking.  Or just eat the mistake without making it larger and not liking it much (been there.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal yes. Edible but not great is often improved by a spicy sauce (or a dairy-based one, if the problem was an excess  of spice in the first place).  The sauce could come from a bottle.

Comment: @ChrisH Sour cream or yoghurt if dairy's not an issue might be the ticket. I'm somewhat out of the habit due to dairy being a problem hyper-locally.

Answer (score 4):

I personally like sausage in meat loaf, but I can see how it might not appeal. Assuming the problem is the seasoning used in the sausage, I'd turn this into a batch of meatballs, then use them in a saucy dish with a complementary flavor.  Divide them up and try them in different dishes, such as Swedish meatballs, spaghetti, barbecue, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would rethink the whole thing and add chilli seasoning and beans. Sometimes trying to hide a strong flavor only makes it worse, so embrace it! Tell the family their having chilli dogs & fries. They will love it and you can freeze any extra chilli.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you did not provide enough information. What recipe did you follow? What is the problem? Too salty or wrong spices? Without knowing what it is that bothers you the most, I can only suggest that you try to either add some ingredients (like grated potatoes to the mix to make it less salty), or try to use the stuff in an entirely new dish / recipe. Like meat balls in a sauce that will pair well with the existing mix.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't tried it with sausage meatloaf, I would recommend adding a lot of onions, since onions add a very nice flavor to meatloaf; they might mask the sausage taste. Don't use big slices of onions (cut them up into little pieces and mix them with the meatloaf). I recommend white onions.

Something else I haven't tried might be to add a little bean flour. Pinto beans (not sure about bean flour) seem to absorb extra grease; so, my hypothesis is that bean flour might make it seem more like hamburger by masking the grease.

Also, if you're making meatloaf patties, I would recommend making the patties thin (not thick), to make them seem less greasy by making a higher percentage of the patty crisp.